# Duplicating incident entity - MS CRM 2011 Incident entity

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I'm trying to duplicate incident entity when click on a custom ribbon button. Everything is ok but i'm having problem with some fields. I'll share the code below.
When i remove the fields that made problem everything works fine, my web resource opens a new entity and populates fields. If i dont remove that fields im getting error. The odd situation is if i create another web resource with fields that i removed from my first Wresource it works fine too. Am i missing something or is there a field restriction ?

The code is working fine:
Comment outted section is making problem.

```js
function test() {
    
    if (Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("customerid").getValue() != null) {
    var CustomerId   = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("customerid").getValue()[0].id;
    var CustomerName = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("customerid").getValue()[0].name;
    var CustomerType = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("customerid").getValue()[0].entityType;
    }
    if (Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_malzeme").getValue() != null) {
    var MatNumbId     = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_malzeme").getValue()[0].id;   
    var MatNumbName   = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_malzeme").getValue()[0].name;
    }
    if (Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_satisburosu").getValue() != null) {
    var SatBurId      = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_satisburosu").getValue()[0].id;
    var SatBurName    = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_satisburosu").getValue()[0].name;
    }
    var Talep       = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_talep").getValue();
    var ilgiliKisi  = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_ilgilikisi").getValue();
    var UrunAdi     = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_urunadi").getValue();
    var Zamanlama   = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_zamanlama").getValue();
    var Email       = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_mail").getValue();
    
    if (Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_siparis").getValue() != null) {
    var SiparisId   = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_siparis").getValue()[0].id;
    var SiparisName = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_siparis").getValue()[0].name;
    }
    var Adet        = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_adet").getValue();
    var Durumu      = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("incidentstagecode").getValue();
    var telefon     = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_telefon").getValue();
    var SrvOzt      = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("title").getValue();
    
    if (Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_mhyetkilisi").getValue() != null) {
    var MHyetkilisiId   = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_mhyetkilisi").getValue()[0].id;
    var MHyetkilisiName = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_mhyetkilisi").getValue()[0].name;
    }
    var islemBelgNo = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_islembelgeno").getValue();
    var Garanti     = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_garanti").getValue();
    var SerTalTuru  = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("casetypecode").getValue();
    var Sevkiyat    = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_sevkiyatsekli").getValue();
    var SerAdrs     = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_servisadresi").getValue();
    var Oncelik     = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("prioritycode").getValue();
    var SemtIlce    = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_semt_ilce").getValue();

    if (Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_sehir").getValue() != null) {
    var SehirId     = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_sehir").getValue()[0].id; 
    var SehirName   = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_sehir").getValue()[0].name;
    }
    var TespitSnc   = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_tespitsonucu").getValue();
    var HataKay     = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_mhhatakaynagi").getValue();
    var HataAdi     = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_hatasebebi").getValue();
    var HataliBrm   = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_hatalibirim").getValue();
    var YplnHata    = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_hataadi").getValue();
    var MHTop       = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_mhtoplanti").getValue();
    var KapanisNdn  = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_kapansnedeni").getValue();

    if (Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_satissor").getValue() != null) {
    var SatSorId      = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_satissor").getValue()[0].id;
    var SatSorName    = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_satissor").getValue()[0].name;
    }
    var Uygunsuzluk = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_uygunsuzlukmaliyeti").getValue();
    
    if (Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_departman").getValue() != null) {
    var DepartmanId   = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_departman").getValue()[0].id;
    var DepartmanName = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_departman").getValue()[0].name;
    }
    var SerTalKay   = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("caseorigincode").getValue();
    var SatFyt      = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_satisfiyati2").getValue();
    
    if (Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_anketiyapan").getValue() != null) {
    var AnketiYapanId = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_anketiyapan").getValue()[0].id;
    var AnketiYapanName = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_anketiyapan").getValue()[0].name;
    }
    var AnketSonucu = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("customersatisfactioncode").getValue();
    var MusteriGors = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_musterigorusleri").getValue();
    var tekraronl   = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_tekraronleme").getValue();
    var Aciklama    = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("description").getValue();

    var parameters  = {};

    if (CustomerId != null && CustomerName != null) {
        parameters["customerid"] = CustomerId;
        parameters["customeridname"] = CustomerName;
        parameters["customeridtype"] = CustomerType;
    }
    if (MatNumbId != null && MatNumbName != null) {
        parameters["new_malzeme"] = MatNumbId;
        parameters["new_malzemename"] = MatNumbName;
    }
   if (SatBurId != null && SatBurName != null) {
        parameters["new_satisburosu"] = SatBurId;
        parameters["new_satisburosuname"] = SatBurName;
    }
    if (Talep != null) {
        parameters["new_talep"] = Talep;
    }
    if (ilgiliKisi != null) {
        parameters["new_ilgilikisi"] = ilgiliKisi;
    }
    if (UrunAdi != null) {
        parameters["new_urunadi"] = UrunAdi;
    }
    if (Zamanlama != null) {
        parameters["new_zamanlama"] = Zamanlama;
    }
    if (Email != null) {
        parameters["new_mail"] = Email;
    }
    if (SiparisId != null &&  SiparisName != null) {
        parameters["new_siparis"] = SiparisId;
        parameters["new_siparisname"] = SiparisName;
    }
    if (Adet != null) {
        parameters["new_adet"] = Adet;
    }
    if (Durumu != null) {
        parameters["incidentstagecode"] = Durumu;
    }
    if (telefon != null) {
        parameters["new_telefon"] = telefon;
    }
    if (SrvOzt != null) {
        parameters["title"] = SrvOzt;
    }
    if (MHyetkilisiId != null && MHyetkilisiName != null) {
        parameters["new_mhyetkilisi"] = MHyetkilisiId;
        parameters["new_mhyetkilisiname"] = MHyetkilisiName;
    }
    if (islemBelgNo != null) {
        parameters["new_islembelgeno"] = islemBelgNo;
    }
    if (Garanti != null) {
        parameters["new_garanti"] = Garanti;
    }
    if (SerTalTuru != null) {
        parameters["casetypecode"] = SerTalTuru;
    }
    if (Sevkiyat != null) {
        parameters["new_sevkiyatsekli"] = Sevkiyat;
    }
    if (SerAdrs != null) {
        parameters["new_servisadresi"] = SerAdrs;
    }
    if (Oncelik != null) {
        parameters["prioritycode"] = Oncelik;
    }
    if (SemtIlce != null) {
        parameters["new_semt_ilce"] = SemtIlce;
    }
   if (TespitSnc != null) {
        parameters["new_tespitsonucu"] = TespitSnc;
    }
    if (HataKay != null) {
        parameters["new_mhhatakaynagi"] = HataKay;
    }
    if (HataAdi != null) {
        parameters["new_hatasebebi"] = HataAdi;
    }
    if (HataliBrm != null) {
        parameters["new_hatalibirim"] = HataliBrm;
    }
    if (YplnHata != null) {
        parameters["new_hataadi"] = YplnHata;
    }
    if (MHTop != null) {
        parameters["new_mhtoplanti"] = MHTop;
    }
    if (KapanisNdn != null) {
        parameters["new_kapansnedeni"] = KapanisNdn;
    }
    /*if (SatSorId != null && SatSorName != null) {
        parameters["new_satissor"] = SatSorId;
        parameters["new_satissorname"] = SatSorName;
    }*/
    if (Uygunsuzluk != null) {
        parameters["new_uygunsuzlukmaliyeti"] = Uygunsuzluk;
    }
    if (DepartmanId != null && DepartmanName != null) {
        parameters["new_departman"] = DepartmanId;
        parameters["new_departmanname"] = DepartmanName;
    }

    Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("incident", null, parameters);
}
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that the fields in question are actually on the form?

Comment: @BlueSam yes, fields are absolutely on the form.